# Capture SSH Response to variable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ssh, ssh.net

I am currently trying to "talk" to a router using SSH commands via C#.

I am using the SSH.net model.

```
public void connectSSH(string hostName, string username, string password)
    {
        using (var client = new SshClient(hostName, username, password))
        {
            client.Connect();
            client.RunCommand(CommandList.showEnvironment());

            client.Disconnect();

        }
    }
```

This is the code I have so far (all the commands are in another file). Ideally I would be able to capture the response of the router to the command, rather than just delivering and executing commands one-way.

How can I capture the response? For example; the command "show environment" responds with a list of factors

Unit Temperature Descr/ID Current/Threshold Range

---

1 Central Temperature/1 27C/11~79C
Status code: * temperature is out of threshold range
Detail Fan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A SshCommand in SSH.net contains the properties Result and Error for responses.
I guess your CommandList is just a List ?
After running your command you should be able to retrieve your result from the 2 properties.